# Does SQL's CREATE TABLE definitions' order matter? What about space between data type and (length)?

Tags: sql, create-table

Example create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `attributes` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

Can I write it as

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` SMALLINT (6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR (63) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `attributes` TEXT DEFAULT NULL NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

Please mind:

- the space between `SMALLINT` and `(6)`, `VARCHAR` and `(63)`,
- the order of `NULL` and `DEFAULT NULL` for column `attributes`.

I tested the above two ways of creating the table in MySQL 57 using HeidiSQL and a similar table definition in SQLite 3 using DB Browser for SQLite, and both of them gave me the same correct table.

So my questions are:

1. How's the SQL standard defined for using `data_type` and `create_definition`?

   Such as the space between the type and its length: `char(80)` vs `char (80)`, `varchar(40)` vs `varchar (40)`

   and the order of *column_definition* (snippet from [MySQL8's create table doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)).     What if I write `DEFAULT` before nullable, `COMMENT` before `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

```
      data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT {literal | (expr)} ]
      [VISIBLE | INVISIBLE]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLLATE collation_name]
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED | DYNAMIC | DEFAULT}]
      [ENGINE_ATTRIBUTE [=] 'string']
      [SECONDARY_ENGINE_ATTRIBUTE [=] 'string']
      [STORAGE {DISK | MEMORY}]
```

2. Is the second way permitted? Will the space in data_type and random order of column_definition work on other DBMS like PostgreSQL?
3. (extra) Is there an online resource of the ISO standard of SQL for us to read, without buying the standard?

Comment: 'How's the SQL standard defined' - don't believe that all manufacturers have implemented sql in the same way.. 'Does create table definitions order matter - not clear what you mean by this but if you have FKs the referenced table but be defined before the table(s) with the FK

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas clearly I use mysql, sqlite and postgresql, which have been asked about in the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon well I meant the order of parts in a column_definition. I've updated the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces won't matter, however the "default null null" is really odd.
SQL datatypes are defined like this:
`MyColumnName` MyDataType null default null collate '...'

If you want your column to be nullable, add it right after your datatype.
In this case use this

```
`attributes` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

and not this

```
`attributes` TEXT DEFAULT NULL NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```